# Sum of i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

this might be a basic question,but given i.i.d. random variables $X_1,X_2, \cdots, X_n$, is the sum of them equal to $nX_k$ for $k \in [1,n]$?
I think not, because if say $X_1 = X_3$, then $X_1$'s value is entirely dependent on $X_3$ (so they are in fact not i.i.d.). Is this a correct reasoning, if so (or not), what other ways can I show it's not correct?
(Would the sum NEVER equal to the result I said?)

Also, how would I sum these variables?

Comment: I guess your question is if $X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d to $X$, then does $ X_1 +X_2 + \ldots +X_n \overset{d}{=} nX$?

Comment: Yep, I think so, I'm kind of new to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Sums of random variables just characterize how certain events go (for example, interarrival times, dice rolls, random number generation). There is, in my eyes, no way to "add" random variables together.

To determine how a sum of IID variables is distributed, I would use moment-generating functions: For a random variable $X$, its moment-generating function is defined as

$$ M_X (t) = E(e^{tX}). $$

Now the cool thing is if you have a sum of IID random variables, we have

$$ M_{\sum X_j} (t) = \prod M_{X_j} (t). $$

That is - the moment generating function of a sum is a product of generating functions.